# React Native Firebase - Android 10 notification does not appear after a while

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

*By the way: I am not sure that is about Android version but my Android 9 device is working correctly, not working on Android 10*

Notifications work for other cases (ex: when app is active or background)

**The problem is: when app is waiting on background and phone is locked for 7-10 minutes, notification does not appear.**

After unlocking the phone notification appear correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the problem is phone is sleeping after a while, so used a foreground notification service library to keep phone awake and **solved issue** with this workaround. I hope this helps:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supersami/rn-foreground-service

and there is a documentation for this package:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-native-foreground-service-f7fc8e617fba

Please comment if you have questions, I would like to help.